# Sound on youtube works, but no offline sound, why is it so?

Tags: nvidia, sound

the sound of my pc is from the integrated audio chip within the gtx-1050-ti, which is connected to the tv using a hdmi cable.
I have got Ubuntu suite 16.04 installed.

When I open a random clip on youtube or another internet platform, there is sound, but when I open a clip from the harddisk, the movie is working but no sound at all.

I have tried to fix it by installing a package of proprietary codecs, namely ubuntu-restricted-extras with no success.

Please, even if you do not know how to fix it, tell me how your first steps would be in finding the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install "**pulseaudio volume control**" :
in "playback" tab, you can choose audio device for each running audio program.

PulseAudio is a network-capable sound server program distributed via the freedesktop.org project. See [this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PulseAudio)

pulseaudio volume control can be installed either through the software center or via the command line with `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`

Comment: thx, this is it, what is pulseaudio in a sentence?

Answer (score 3):

If it is purely opening local files then the answer is more likely to be that you do not have the correct codec installed to decode the audio in the file.

You could start by trying to install these packages.  Getting the right gstreamer plugin combination does appear to occasionally be a black art but these are the ones I have installed right now:

> apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3

Failing that, you could try with "vlc" as an alternative more likely to work the first time.  Lastly if you open the video file on the command line, the terminal output may hint as to which decoder you are missing.  You could try this

> xdg-open /path/to/file.mkv

Answer (score 0):

I'd first try:
Sound Preferences -> Hardware -> HDMI -> OFF -> Close

...or the other one off if using HDMI sound

Comment: Hardware? Do you mean Output? Off? Could you improve the clarity of this answer? What flavor of Ubuntu 16.04 did you get this from?

Comment: As @ElderGeek said, try and clarify some more detailed instructions and data about your setup. (Possibly some screenshots if you can.)